# Composite Graph from Crossfilter Example

Tags: dc.js

Starting from the payments example crossfilter (https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference) how may we create a Composite Chart with one Line Chart for each payment type (tab, visa, cash)?

Comment: +1. I am at a loss on how to create it using the composite chart. I think this can be done using the series chart. However i will wait for the expert's advice

Comment: At the moment I'm looking for a composite cart example because what I really want is to chart two series and use .useRightYAxis(true) so that I can be comparing two data sets with different Y axis values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you want to display payment `totals` over time (the `date` dimension) for each payment `type`.

```
var payments = crossfilter([...]);

var dateDimension = payments.dimension(function(d) { return new Date(d.date); });
```

Create a group of payment totals for each payment type (tab, visa, cash)

```
var totalForType = function(type) {
  return function(d) {
    return d.type === type ? d.total : null;
  };
};

var tabTotalsGroup  = dateDimension.group().reduceSum(totalForType('tab'));
var visaTotalsGroup = dateDimension.group().reduceSum(totalForType('visa'));
var cashTotalsGroup = dateDimension.group().reduceSum(totalForType('cash'));
```

Define a composite chart and use the groups to define 3 line charts as part of the composite chart.

```
var compositeChart = dc.compositeChart('#composite-chart');
compositeChart
  ...
  .x(d3.time.scale().domain([new Date("2011-11-14T16:15:00Z"), new Date("2011-11-14T17:45:00Z")]))
  .dimension(dateDimension)
  .compose([
    dc.lineChart(compositeChart).group(tabTotalsGroup, 'tab').colors(['#ffaa00']),
    dc.lineChart(compositeChart).group(visaTotalsGroup, 'visa').colors(['#aa00ff']),
    dc.lineChart(compositeChart).group(cashTotalsGroup, 'cash').colors(['#00aaff'])
  ]);

 dc.renderAll();
```

Full example: http://plnkr.co/edit/rhDURrDfeSvVqEnQR9L1?p=preview

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  I changed it to a bar chart which makes a bit more sense in this context.  With this as a starting point I was able to adapt it to what I was actually trying to accomplish.