# Crossfilter.js / dc.js - Groups filtering different column in dataset

Tags: dc.js

newbie with crossfilter (in javascript, more precisely) here.

I have a database with the same idea as below and I want to plot a composite graph in dc.js + crossfilter.js with one line for each axis. In this case, I'll show only one sensor at a time. Note that for each sensor, the values for the axis share the same seconds.

I'm creating a dimension with the 'seconds' and I want to create a group for each 'axis' but I need to filter the values of 'seconds' based on the 'axis'. For instance, to create the line in the chart for axis 'x', I need to use the dimension 'seconds' and a group with 'value', but only those from the axis x.

```
seconds ; sensor ; axis ; value
      1 ;   head ;    x ;    10
      2 ;   head ;    x ;     9
      3 ;   head ;    x ;     7
      1 ;   head ;    y ;    11
      2 ;   head ;    y ;     5
      3 ;   head ;    y ;     4
      1 ;  waist ;    x ;    11
      2 ;  waist ;    x ;     5
      3 ;  waist ;    x ;     4
```

I tried some options, but no success so far.

Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind, found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32397132/composite-graph-from-crossfilter-example Thanks anyway!